# Is there a better way to direct users after adding/editing an entry?

Tags: channel-entries, structure, entries

A thing that annoys me about EE and Structure is that when I add/edit an entry within a channel, I get redirected back to Structure main page. I might want to add another entry, edit another entry in that same channel or edit that same particular entry again.

Always throwing me back to the Structure page is annoying. I feel like I'm clicking around way too much.

Anyone got any good addons or ideas to handle this better? Something that gives you an option to go somewhere after or as you save?

Thanks,

Dave

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[**Deviant**](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/deviant) is great for this.

> Deviant allows you to control, globally or on a per-channel basis,
>   where authors land after publishing, updating or deleting entries in
>   the EE control panel.

You can choose to route users to:

- Default Preview
- Publish Form
- Edit Entry
- Manage Entries
- Pages module
- Structure module
- Zenbu module

[image: Deviant Extension]

Comment: Great add-on, use it all the time!

Comment: Never heard of this add-on - brilliant! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable Structure’s entry redirection:

Module -> Structure -> Module Settings -> **Redirect to Structure on entry publish/save -> No**

In addition I use the [QuickSave](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/quicksave) add-on to stay on the edit page when saving an entry (QuickSave settings: **‘Save & Close’ Destination -> Edit Entries Page**)

[SC Publish Redirect](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/sc-publish-redirect) is another add-on. But I have not tested it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always disable that and use default EE function when you got Preview and you can Publish another entry of the same channel or Edit that entry. You can disable this in Structure Preferences.

About other add-on handling redirects, its something I want to know too :)

Answer (score 0):

If you go to Add-Ons > Modules > Structure > Settings > Module Settings the second option is "Redirect to Structure on entry publish/save" which you will want to set to "No" in your case to enable the default publish/edit functionality in EE.

If you want to go beyond that you would need to write an extension to handle the behaviors you want. There isn't an existing add-on that I am aware of right now.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this addon that allows you to do specific redirects based on the channel entry being added/updated/deleted. Think it might do the trick.

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/deviant